# How to build customer docker image for Amazon elastic inference for Sagemaker inference in PyTorch

Tags: docker, amazon-sagemaker

I am trying to build a customer docker image for Sagemaker elastic inference.
I read the document page, https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/ei.html#ei-intro-endpoint
and
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/ei-endpoints.html#ei-endpoints-boto3
https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-pytorch-inference-toolkit#building-your-image
I do not see an example showing how to build customized docker container.
If you know how to build a customized docker container for Sagemaker elastic inference,  could you help me and show me how to do it?
The docker container will be used in cloudformation file to build the Sagemaker endpoint.

```
Type: AWS::SageMaker::Model
Properties: 
  Containers: 
    - ContainerDefinition
  EnableNetworkIsolation: Boolean
  ExecutionRoleArn: String
  InferenceExecutionConfig: 
    InferenceExecutionConfig
  ModelName: String
  PrimaryContainer: 
    ContainerDefinition
  Tags: 
    - Tag
  VpcConfig: 
    VpcConfig
'''

Thanks,
```

Answer (score 1):

there are better alternatives that may be cheaper and more performant than Amazon Elastic Inference such as the GPU accelerated ml.g4dn.xlarge and AWS Inferentia instances.

Can you evaluate these options for your workload and consider using them instead of Amazon Elastic Inference?

You can use the Amazon SageMaker Inference Recommender to benchmark and compare performance of these options for your workload. Here is a sample price-performance comparison of various hardware acceleration options on Amazon SageMaker based on US-East-1 pricing -

| Instance name | On-Demand hourly rate | vCPU | Memory | Storage | Network performance. |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ml.g4dn.xlarge | $0.736 | 4 | 16 GiB | 125 GB NVMe SSD | Up to 25 Gigabit |
| ml.inf1.xlarge | $0.297 | 4 | 8 | any EBS | Up to 25 Gigabit |
| ml.eia2.xlarge* | $0.476 | n/a | n/a | n/a | n/a |

In terms of a custom docker image for EI,

Is there a reason you need a Bring Your Own Container (BYOC) can you not make use of one of SageMaker's containers?

You need to make sure your DL framework is EI compatible. For example, if you read https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elastic-inference/latest/developerguide/ei-tensorflow.html, you can find that pip install -U ei_for_tf*.whl is required. That means the tf version is different from the generic one.

If you use DL AMI or DL images by AWS, the package has been pre-installed.